# Testing backwards compatibility of Xamarin Apps

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We've hit a few cases recently were we have wanted to upgrade local database data structure or the user settings and we've almost broken backwards compatibility.

1. How do people test there development "Work In Progress" with a
   released version of an app?
2. Do you update your AndroidManifest and
   Info.Plist versions after each release? We are currently just
   setting them at the time of creating the IPA and that change is not
   added back into the repo

Comment: What is the mean of `broken backwards compatibility` ? Did the app crash ?

Comment: We were writing a setting to a "settings repository". As an example,a setting called "Apples_Chosen" but in the new version it is switched to a more gerneic "Preferred_{fruit}" as we were now dealing with multiple fruit. We needed to deal with the old "Apples_Chosen" setting and migrate it to a "Preferred_Apple" value. Failure to do so would "break" the app